# lock eth indefinitely instead of time

Tags: solidity

I've seen a lot of examples of time locking eth but what about locking for an indefinite amount of time allowing the user to initiate a withdrawal at their discretion? Any examples or technical document links appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? It should be an easy thing to lock ether in a contract, and allow the user to retrieve them at their convenience.